# I don't understand the single quota mark in this syntax

Tags: ballerina

I was creating an Open API / Swagger client using the CLI.  It created a `getSerializedArray` function that used the following syntax:

```
    return string:'join("", ...arrayValues);
```

I don't understand that syntax: `string:'join...`

What is the single quote doing?  This is hard to Google.

Also, what are the multiple things that the single quote does?  I know about the [quoted identifier](https://hindujab.medium.com/quoted-identifiers-in-ballerina-be7e0f0f4441), but this seems to be a different case here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string:'join` is a function with the identifier `'join` in the `lang.string` lang library in Ballerina. `join` is a reserved keyword and is not allowed to be used as an identifier.

[image]

Therefore, the function is defined with a `quoted identifier`.

see [https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.string/0.0.0/functions#'join](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.string/0.0.0/functions#%27join)

Therefore the single quote is used in the function definition to escape the reserved keyword and preserve the semantic meaning of the `join`.

Answer (score 3):

The quoted identifier does one thing. That is allowing a reserved keyword to be used as an identifier. In this example, `type` is a keyword in Ballerina.

```
record Material {
  string id;
  string 'type;
}
```

If you have non-identifier chars in your identifier, you can escape them using `\` as follows.

```
record Material {
  string id;
  string 'type;
  string item\-id;
}
```

Now, say you see this syntax in Ballerina `foo:bar`. It means you use the public symbol `bar` in module `foo`. If that public symbol name is a reserved keyword, then you have to use quoted identifier syntax to use that symbol. `foo:'join`